# Prevent same user from login from multiple devices nodejs JWT tokens

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am making a student website where a user can login using google login with firebase and custom jwt tokens are created for a user.
Now if a same user login from other browser then he/she should be automatically logged out from the first browser. As of now I have created a variable names `isLoggedIn` and set is `false` by default. When the user do google login its browser is saved in database and isLoggediN becomes true.

Now I need to ask how to move further that it logged out from the first browser and overwrite the second browser in database

here is the code:

```
export const signin = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const code = req.body.code;
    console.log(code + "code");
 
    let profile = await verifyIdToken(code);
    console.log(profile + "signinuser");
    const newUser = {
      
      name: profile.name,
      email: profile.email,
      
      isLoggedIn:true,
      userBrowser: req.headers["user-agent"]
      
};

if(newUser.isLoggedIn) {
  console.log("you are already logged in with browser: {newUser.userBrowser}");
}
else {
  console.log('isLoggefIn is true');
}

            let user = await db.aggregate('USER', query);
    user = user[0];
    if (!user) {
      user = await db.create('USER', newUser);
    }
    const token = generateToken(user);
    console.log(token + "signindata");
    res.status(200).json({ user, token });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)                                                                                             
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};

export const refreshToken = async (req, res) => {
  try {
            let user = await db.aggregate('USER', query);
    user = user[0];
    const token = generateToken(user);
    console.log(token + "token")
    res.status(200).json({ user, token});
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};
```

middleware:

```
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const isCustomAuth = token?.length < 500;
    if (!token) 
    {return res.status(401).json({ message: "No token provided" });}
    let decodedData; 
    if(token && isCustomAuth){
    decodedData= verifyToken(token);
    console.log(decodedData + "data");
    req.userId = decodedData?.id;
    }
    else{
      decodedData = jwt.decode(token);
      console.log(decodedData + "decoded token");
      req.userId = decodedData?.sub;
    }
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(403).json({ message: "Token is not valid" });
    
  }
};

export default auth;
```

Reducers

```
const authReducer = (state = { user: null, authenticated: false }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionType.AUTH:
      localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(action?.user.token));

      return { ...state, user: action?.user.user, loading: false, authenticated: true, errors: null };
    case actionType.LOGOUT:
      localStorage.clear();

      return { ...state, user: null, loading: false, authenticated: false, errors: null };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

frontend:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user?.authenticated && localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      dispatch(refreshToken(history));
    }
  });


  
  const signInWithGooglee = async () => {
    try {
      let code = await signInWithGoogle();
      dispatch(signin({ code: code }, history));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

{
              user.authenticated ? <  Button variant="contained" color="success"  onClick={() => dispatch(logout(history))} >Logout</Button>
                : <Button variant="contained" color="success"  onClick={signInWithGooglee}>Login</Button>
            }
```

Please help in finding out how to automatically logout from one browser if logged in from other browser.

Comment: What's the purpose of the token created using `generateToken`? Which token do you use to authenticate users in subsequent requests after login? You might have to store some "latestSessionId" in your database and if the token's session ID is not same as latest session, you can return unauthorized errors and log user out on client.

Comment: What you're describing isn't really the way that Firebase Auth was designed.  It's expected the users might sign in from multiple devices and stay signed in on all of them until they choose to sign out.  If you don't want this behavior, you'll have to somehow manually store and manage the tokens from devices and (on your backend) [revoke](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens) the ones that should not be able to stay signed in.

Comment: couldn't you store all the tokens in your database as an array and when a user logs in you can remove the existing token and replace it with the new one?

Comment: generate token is for creating the access token for the user. After login access token and then refresh token.
I am not using session then session id wont i be able to handle @Dharmaraj

Comment: @DougStevenson I am creating my own custom token to manage the authentication, therefoe i am asking how to revoke when user signin with other browser

Comment: @async: I could not get you?

Comment: You can just use some package like UUID and add it in your access token while signing it and then store the UUID in user's document in the database. So you can compare the IDs later.

Comment: i am already saving uid in database for a specific user. Can you please provide the sample code it will be really helpful to understand @Dharmaraj.

Comment: Tokens are not really the right auth mechanism for a situation where you only want the user signed in one place.  While, you could hack something together, it's really a misuse of tokens which are meant to stand-alone and support any number of logins.  Something like a server-side session where you can easily invalidate previous session/logins whenever any new login happens would be much more straightforward to implement.

Comment: @jfriend00: can you please provide the sample code of what you are saying. actually i am a newbie so its my first project i am working on. Thanks

Comment: @jfriend00: I have created a variable named isLoggedIn which check the status of login but dont know how to check the same on logged out

Comment: @Tanyamaheshwari for example, lets say in your database every user has a tokens string (from the User Schema). If this string isn't '', you can replace the token that the database stored from a login elsewhere with the one the user has gotten from logging in just now. This would invalidate the other login, leaving only one device/browser logged in. Would that work?

Comment: @async:  hey can you please provide me the sample code for this. 
I am using access token and refresh tokens both?
it will be really vry helpful.

Comment: what database are you using like mongoose/mongodb, sql etc?

Comment: database is mongodb/mongoose

Comment: alright ill type it as an answer, lmk if you don't understand something or the answer isnt the same format as your original code

Comment: Sure definitely. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245526/discussion-between-tanya-maheshwari-and-async).

Answer (score 0):

You can save the tokens in a token array in the database, and if theres already an existing token in the database when the user logs in, remove it and replace it with the latest token.

User schema (assuming you use mongoose, can edit for mongoDb alone)

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({


    ... // other fields
    tokens: {
        accessToken: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        refreshToken {
            type: String,
            required: false
        }
    }
})
```

Login

```
const user = User.findOne({your paramaters for finding the user}) // or however you find the user
// check user credentials match up
if (user.tokens.accessToken != '') {
// setting the tokens to '', invalidating previous login
   user.tokens.accessToken = ''
   user.tokens.refreshToken = ''
   user.save()
}
// continue with login
```

Explanation if you need to use mongoDb:
change your user schema to have a 'tokens' object, which itself has two objects, accessToken and refreshToken. Store the appropriate tokens in each.
then, in your login function, you can check if these objects are empty or not, and if they arent, set them to ''. this invalidates the login from a different browser/device, and set them to the current tokens.

Comment: ValidationError: tokens.refreshToken: Path `tokens.refreshToken` is required., tokens.accessToken: Path `tokens.accessToken` is required. geting error how to resolve this?

Comment: sorry, set `required` to false in the user schema

Comment: Hey I need to ask how to save Tokens while creating user req.body.code. It should be like req.body.code for accessToken?

Comment: user.save is not a function error. can you please look at above code and let me know where should i place the code which you have provided?

Comment: I am facing too many errors: user.tokens.accessToken not getting read. Secondly refreshToken is not getting saved

Comment: can you please help in placing this in above given code structure? @async: thanks