# star rating value from React to Mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am working to show the rating for every college that is shown to user based on user score. Suppose user A gives college 1 as rating 5, then the rating will be send to mongodb database
In database I have made a collection named rating

```
 ratingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        rating: Number,
        userId: {
            ref: 'users', 
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId 
            // a string or whatever your id is
        },
        collegeId: {
            ref: 'colleges', 
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId
        },
    })

const Rating = mongoose.model('rating', ratingSchema);
```

The query written in nodeJS file is:

```
Rating
    .findOne({})
    .populate('userId')
    .populate('collegeId');
```

How to post the rating from react to mongodb.

the function made in react is :
component/Report.js

```
const StarRating = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      {Array(5)
        .fill(0)
        .map((_, idx) => (
          <label key={idx}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="rating"
              onChange={handleRate}
              value={props.ratingValue}
              checked={idx === props.ratingValue}
            />
            <FaStar color={idx < 3 ? "#01af93" : "#bbb"} />
          </label>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Report = (props) => {
  
 
  const { advices } = useSelector((state) => state.advice);
  
  const [rate, setRating] = useState(null);

  

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!advices) {
      dispatch(fetchAdvices(history));
    }  
  }); 

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchRate() {
      try {
        const { rating } = await api.get(paths.FETCH_RATING);
        console.log(rating + "user rating");
      } catch(error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchRate();
  }, []);



 const handleRate = async() => {

  const rate  =  await api.post(paths.UPDATE_RATING, {rating:rate});
 props.setRating(rate)
  
 }
   
  return (
        
            <>
             <Container> 
  
              <Grid>
              <Fragment>
                <Grid >
          <Card>
         
        <CardContent><> <div>
      <StarRating setRating={(val) => setRate(val)} ratingValue={rate} />
    </div></></CardContent>
           </Card>
  </Grid>
  
  
  </>
          
  )};
```

i want to set rating for college and next time when user sees the order of colleges will be in the highest ranking to lowest ranking.

Comment: Do you have a controller handles inserting new record to database?

Comment: Yes in that controller I have written a query:  `Rating
    .findOne({})
    .populate('userId')
    .populate('collegeId');`
this controller is showing the college based on user score.

Comment: No I mean like new Rating({rating:5}); await Rating.save();.
You need an endpoint like that to insert new document. (assuming Rest api)

Comment: No i dont have that, i have to post the rating from frontend I thought of doing this using useEffect and using axios.post

Comment: can u please detailed it out what u think is right

Comment: ok I can provide an example route. You need that endpoint to give axios.post as first argument. What is your backend? express?

Comment: Backend is nodejs express  Thank U

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245829/discussion-between-tanya-maheshwari-and-linusw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/ratings', async (req, res) => {
  const { rating, collegeId } = req.body;

// just an example to userId, depends on your authentication method
  const userId = req.user.id

// example validation
  if (!rating || !collegeId) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: 'bad request.' });
  }

  try {
    const newRating = new Rating({rating, collegeId, userId})
    await newRating.save()
    return res.status(201).json({message:"success", rating:newRating})
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: 'database error' });
  }
});
```

then you can axios.post("yourApiUrl/ratings", {rating: 5, collegeId:123456})

```
router.get('/ratings', async (req, res) => {
  try {
// maybe you need modify I didn't memorize mongoose methods
    const ratings = await Rating.find({userId}
    .populate('userId')
    .populate('collegeId').sort({rating:1});
    return res.status(201).json({message:"success", ratings})
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: 'database error' });
  }
});
```

this route gives ordered by user ratings.

Comment: Hi, one more thing if i want user to show the colleges he rated from highes to lowest then sorting should be done, where and how?

Comment: Thanks can you please help me out with : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72585959/prevent-same-user-from-login-from-multiple-devices-nodejs-jwt-tokens

Comment: @Tanyamaheshwari edited the code for getting ordered ratings. I will look other question shortly.

Comment: thanks, just updating my set of code and thanks for your immense help.

Comment: in front end while posting collegeid is predefined and coming from other schema then what should I put in that?

Comment: At that point you should have had fetched and stored collegeId already. In state, prop or url param. Whatever fits your component design.

Comment: collegeId i have already fetched and stored. then I am working ahead. Thanks.
Did u see the other questions? @linusw:

Comment: @Tanyamaheshwari Yes I checked, I have no experience with firebase authentication. I won't be any help there.

Comment: without firebase authentication can u make it possible with just checking the login status and removing the tokens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245831/discussion-between-linusw-and-tanya-maheshwari).